# What is a high performing network architecture to use in a PPO2 MlpLnLstmPolicy RL model?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-ai

I am playing around with creating [custom architectures in stable-baselines](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html#examples). Specifically I am training an agent using a [PPO2](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html) model.

**My question is, are there some rules of thumb or best practices in network architecture (of actor and critic networks) to achieve higher performance i.e. larger rewards?**

For example, I find that usually using wider layers (e.g. 256 rather than 128 units) and adding more layers (e.g. a deep network with 5 layers rather than 2) achieves a smaller RMSE (better performance) for time series prediction when training an LSTM. Would similar conventions apply to reinforcement learning - would adding more layers to the actor and critic network have higher performance - does sharing an input layer work well?